# Not outputting string to file

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

The following code is supposed to output the contents of a database field to a file but it is only returning the `lastid` (which is wanted) and then it says Arrray.

By the way `$db->query` returns a result set. Any tips on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
// this is to test values
$myFile = "debugdirectory.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile,"w");

$res = $db->q("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$res = mysql_result($res,0,0);

fwrite($fh,$res);
$string = $db->qarray(
  "SELECT field32 FROM business_db WHERE id='{$res}'"
);

$new = "";
foreach($string as $s){
    fwrite($fh,$s);
}
```

Comment: What are you doing there? `mysql_result` does not return strings, so whats the plan?

Comment: http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php   It returns the result of a row. I am trying to output my result which is stored in $string to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before going too far, I would suggest you to debug what's the content of `$string` first.

simply type:

```
var_dump( $string );
```

just after:

```
$string = $db->qarray("SELECT field32 FROM business_db WHERE id='{$res}'");
```

would be enough.
After you examine the content then you can then decide what to do, eg:

- write here it's contents, if you still unsure what to do next.
- adjust your code, if you already know what to do.

Comment: i read that it is supposed to output the contents to the screen however nothing is happening with var_dump($string)

Comment: are you sure? if var_dump return nothing, I thing you have output buffering somewhere in your code. Btw, what is $db? is it custom database wrapper classes?

Comment: yes, it is a custom class my problem has been solved thanks all

Comment: great, choose which answer fit you best. If no one, write down the solution to your problem and mark it as accepted.